# Custom theme for tabbed page's in android

Tags: android, xamarin, android-theme, tabbedpage

[image]

I have made an app for android with `Xamarin` form in `VS2015`. I have added `TabbedPage`, but my `TabbedPage's` action bar has problem.

If tabbedPage has many `ContentPage`, title text is not `1 line`, and I can't change tab's `height`, `width`, `color`(font, background), and `scrollable` tab.

I know the problem is `theme`, but I don't know how do I customized theme.

**Below is my theme:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <resources>
        <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
        </style>
        <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
        <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette-->
            <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
            <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
            <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
             which is used to tint widgets -->
            <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
            <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
             colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
            <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
            <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
        </style>
        <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
            <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

now, my app need `AppCompact` theme, so I don't know how do I fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `"scrollable"` Tab mode.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout" />
```

Here I used customized `TabLayout` style. Below is the `MyCustomTabLayout` style. Define this style into your `values/styles.xml` file.

**values/styles.xml**

```
<!-- TabLayout Style -->
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">3dp</item>
    <item name="tabBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

If your style theme is AppCompact(see in manifest file) then your class should be extend AppCompactActivity class otherwise it will throw error.
I think viewPager is comfortable to use.

**Look at This code How i change textcolor,height,tabindicator color in ViewPager**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#499b97"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#cfc31b"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<style name="MyTrasparent" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/soloColor</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
```